# How to remove the placeholder once set value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm unable to remove the placeholder after set the user name.

Anyone have idea how to remove place holder once set user name by using console

[image]
Link : https://login.microsoftonline.com

```
document.getElementById("i0116").value = "singapore@mail.com"
```

Comment: That's not where the placeholder is coming from. [It's coming from a div](https://i.imgur.com/gLxfhJK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is, Microsoft didn't used native HTML `placeholder`. They have added extra `div` for `placeholder`. You just need to hide that `div` after setting the `value`. Please see following code

```
document.getElementById("i0116").value = "singapore@mail.com";
document.getElementsByClassName("phholder")[0].style.display = "none";
```

**Modified:**

Microsoft is using Knockout for data binding. That's why you need to fire change event to set the values in ViewModel. Use following code after above two lines.

```
var event = new Event('change');
document.getElementById("i0116").dispatchEvent(event)
```

Comment: Thanks i'm able to remove the placeholder. After i called "document.getElementById('idSIButton9').click()". Then i'm getting error " Enter a valid email address or phone number. "

Comment: See modified answer. Please accept the answer if satisfied. :)